# Parameters in onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I'm reading about the Use of OnItemClick Paramter in this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Can any one explain me the exact difference between 3rd & 4th Parameters(position & id)

**position  int:** The position of the view in the adapter.

**id    long:** The row id of the item that was clicked.

- Both are returning position of an Row Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often position and id are the same, but they do not have to be. Position is the index in the underlying dataset, whether it is an array, ArrayList, or Cursor. `id` is a unique identifier for the object displayed in the child view. For example, this can be the primary key for a row in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Position is the position index of the item in the adapter
id is the id of the item in that position that is returned from `getItemId()` which is row index by default.